# Determine the intent filter for a receiver from the package info

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I need to retrieve the action name for the intent filters against the receiver from a particular package, which got installed. I am receiving the broadcast intent for `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL`.

I am getting the `uuid` for that package. But, how can I get the details of the receivers wired for that  package? Probably from the `PackageManager` or `PackageInfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get Package information , after apks has been installed.
then you can use this -

```
  <receiver android:name="PackageChangeReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
  <data android:scheme="package"/>
     </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Now in your receiver -

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
   Log.d(TAG, "The Package Name is " + getPackageName(intent);
 }

 String getPackageName(Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    String pkg = uri != null ? uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null;
    return pkg;
}
```

Comment: I have figured out another approach using the data-string of the intent.
String dataString = intent.getDataString();
String[] split_str = dataString.split(":");
String packageName = split_str[1];